# How to use scipy.stats expect function?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I was expecting

```
scipy.stats.norm.expect(loc = 55, scale = 1)
```

returns the mean of the distribution 55 , instead it returns 3.9096876333292135e-108.
Am I using it wrong? Can anyone explain to me how this function works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be a bug. You have understood the manual correctly, but it turns out that if the `"loc"` is greater than 35.6, then things get abnormal. Otherwise, it works as expected.

Comment: Yes, but the 'cut-off` depends on scale, is further out for larger values of scale.

Answer (score 1):

The problem:

```
import scipy.stats
#expect(func, loc=0, scale=1, lb=None, ub=None, conditional=False, **kwds)

for i in range(26, 55):
    print scipy.stats.norm.expect(loc=i,scale=1),
```

output:

```
26.0
27.0
28.0
29.0
30.0
31.0
32.0
33.0
34.0
35.0
3.36373206533e-10
1.24696133938e-13
1.7005527212e-17
8.53164410131e-22
1.57463854604e-26
1.06913991702e-31
2.670507049e-37
2.45390887262e-43
8.29523418554e-50
1.03158350625e-56
4.71938759035e-64
7.94277793838e-72
4.91773037097e-80
1.12011477121e-88
9.38568238273e-98
2.89317497775e-107
3.28087032536e-117
1.4932849185e-127
3.63870849201e-118
```

For larger `scale` (standard deviation) the 'cut-off' for the behavior moves further out, as you would expect.

The `problem can be 'fixed'  by setting the lower and upper bounds explicitly`, as seen here:

```
import numpy as np

for i in np.arange(5,100,5):
    print i,scipy.stats.norm.expect(loc=55,lb=-i,ub=i,scale=1)
```

output:

```
5 0.0
10 0.0
15 0.0
20 2.01210143973e-267
25 1.05364770562e-196
30 7.87517644756e-137
35 8.61623210583e-88
40 1.40277331283e-49
45 3.46495136419e-22
50 1.42791169386e-05
55 27.1010577196
60 54.9999827474
65 55.0
70 55.0
75 55.0
80 55.0
85 55.0
90 55.0
95 55.0
```

But there must be a subtle bug. If you look at the [source](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/_modules/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.html) (see **init** method of class `rv_continous`) you'll find that the default limits are imported as Numpy's 'inf'. 
If you run the limits explicitly as +/- np.inf  you get the same behavior as the OP described:

```
for i in np.arange(5,60,5):
    print i,scipy.stats.norm.expect(loc=i,lb=-np.inf,ub=np.inf,scale=1)
```

Output:

```
5 5.0
10 10.0
15 15.0
20 20.0
25 25.0000000007
30 30.0
35 35.0
40 1.57463854604e-26
45 1.03158350625e-56
50 9.38568238273e-98
55 3.90968763333e-108
```

Also note that in the definition of `expect` in the [source](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/_modules/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.html), integration warnings are silenced:

```
    # Silence floating point warnings from integration.
    olderr = np.seterr(all='ignore')
    vals = integrate.quad(fun, lb, ub, **kwds)[0] / invfac
```

Very likely the source of the problem is in how `integrate.quad` treats limits when given as +/- `np.inf`.  The actual [source for the integration is in Fortran](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/integrate/quadpack/dqagie.f), but a rough description of how numerical integration is done for infinite intervals (mapping to a finite range, just like in case of Riemann sphere) is given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Integrals_over_infinite_intervals).

Comment: If you give someone a downvote, please help them with a comment on how to do better.

Comment: I think 'loc = 55' in the question moves the center of the distribution to 55, and the pdf should be np.exp(-(x-55)**2/2)/np.sqrt(2*np.pi) which is much larger around 55.